# How can I get the store code inside a block in the product page using the dependency injection?

Tags: store-view, dependency-injection, magento2.4, store-code

I have to check which is the current store view. In order to do that I was using the Object Manager to get the store code like this:

```
$storeCode = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class)
    ->getStore()
    ->getCode();

if ($storeCode === "en") {
   ...
};
if ($storeCode === "it") {
   ...
};
```

but doing this way in no more recommended, instead I should use the dependency injection technique...

how should I use it?

Comment: where you added above code ?

Comment: @Pawan I added it on my theme template file `app/design/frontend/MyTheme/MyDefault/Magento_Catalog/templates/my-template.phtml`

Comment: please have a look at https://github.com/pawankparmar/Siteinfo/blob/master/Vendor/Siteinfo/Block/Siteinfo.php

Comment: you can use same block class and get `$block->getStoreCode();` in your phtml file

Comment: Thanks but I cannot understand how I can use it inside the theme. I just added `Block/Siteinfo.php` and correct accordingly the namespace path. Then in my template file `Magento_Theme/templates/my-template.phtml` I added `echo $block->getStoreCode();` but it didn't work.

Comment: I meant, echo doesn't print anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113930/discussion-between-pawan-and-kamzata).

Answer (score 0):

In your block file constructor, add StoreManager dependency like shown in code below :

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
            
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;      
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $data);
    }
```

Then you can get any value related to store like this:

```
$currentStoreId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
```

I think in place of getId() you can write getCode(). Happy Coding.

Comment: Can I also get the current product?

Comment: That's another question pls open a new thread. and if my answer helped you pls accept it as a solution. thanks.